# What am I missing in the following buttons code?

Tags: android, button

I am trying to increment and decrement the middle textview via buttons on the sides. The application starts up finely but by the time I click on any of the buttons it gets closed with following error.
 `Error: process <package> has stopped unexpectedly.`

My main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="80dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
     />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="40dp" />
```

My java file:

```
public class IncrementDecrementActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView tv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            tv.setText(counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            tv.setText(counter);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Post the logcat details so that other programmers help you :)

Comment: 06-13 16:17:37.404: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

I am not sure how do I copy all logcat details :-/

Comment: Without all details we won't be able to help. Check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. This should be.

In this statement

```
counter--;
tv.setText(counter);
```

It should be

```
counter--;
tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

I guess the error is

> ResourceNotFoundException

How you encountered this error?

on the code above.

you declared `int counter;`

let's consider the value of counter is 0

and then

you called

```
counter--; // take note this is an integer
tv.setText(counter);
```

counter is now -1

by calling [setText(counter);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

will search first a string value from strings.xml with an integer -1 and set the text to textview

If android fails to find that string it will throw `ResourceNotFoundException`

:)

Comment: He's calling TextView.setText(int resID) instead of TextView.setText(CharSequence text)

:)

Comment: It worked, thanks. But what is the problem with setText? Its working fine when I pass ("Total="+counter) and crashes with (counter).

Comment: @Remdroid I was calling TextView.setText(CharSequence text)